# AppendListItem with Correct GlyphType

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, bulletedlist, numbered-list

I'm trying to copy a ListItem with its associated GlyphType with the following code.

```
if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM ) {
    Logger.log("Glyph: " + element.getGlyphType());
    newDocBody.appendListItem(element).setGlyphType(element.getGlyphType());
}
```

The log output shows a GlyphType of NUMBER but the next line sets the GlyphType of the new ListItem as BULLET.

From what I understand of the docs, [getGlyphType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#getGlyphType()) returns an GlyphType object, so couldn't this be used for [setGlyphType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#setGlyphType())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlyphType is an ENUM object (basically, a load of IDs referenced by names) belonging to the DocumentApp class, and is accessed as any other static property.

So, if you wanted to set the bullets to be uppercase letters, you'd say something like:

```
myDocBody.appendListItem( "List item text" )
         .setGlyphType( DocumentApp.GlyphType.LATIN_UPPER );
```

A list of the possible options is available at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your code that you are trying to copy over elements from one document to another. I really think the Google Apps Scripts lacks a lot of functionality - and it shows strange behaviours.

From what I have identified the call to `appendListItem` resets the `glyphType`. I found that this (sort of) works, when `listItem` is a list item copied from another document:

```
// Appending the list item to the body breaks the glyph type.
glyphType = listItem.getGlyphType();
body.appendListItem(listItem);
listItem.setGlyphType(glyphType);
```