# How to sort sections of a GDocs document alphabetically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

**Starting point:** I have a doc with sections separated by page breaks.

**Goal:** I want a Google Apps Script that scans through a doc and sorts the sections alphabetically (aka everything between a heading1 and a page break). The manual equivalent would be cut-pasting sections around until sorted.

To illustrate, here's an example document: [initial state](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aAEpbljU7rjc2g3hCWg0qiZ_bzgaQXuSHtKPG0WMh_8/edit?usp=sharing) and [desired end state](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XBjk1wWlFSla51HS4FnPEQIZrDr8pf8H7dTK61PgxdI/edit?usp=sharing).

So far, this is what I have:

A script that searches through a doc and identifies the headings with a given format (heading1). I could sort the headings alphabetically, but I don't know how to move whole sections around in the document.

```
function findHeading1s() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();//.openById('<doc-id>');
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // Define the search parameters.
  let searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
  let searchHeading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
  let searchResult = null;

  let headers = [];
    
  // Search until the paragraph is found.
  while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
    let par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
    let parText = par.getText();
    if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading && parText != "") {
      headers.push(parText);
      Logger.log(headers); //Headers in current order: [Zone, Template, Example]
    }
  }
  Logger.log(headers.sort()) //[Example, Template, Zone]
}
```

Any ideas how to move everything between a heading and the following pagebreak? I don't mind if the sorted end result is in a new document.

Is this doable with existing GAS capabilities? Tried to debug the body/paragraph elements to get some idea on how to solve this, but I only get the functions of the object, not the actual content. Not super intuitive.

Here are the steps I think are needed:

1. Identify heading1 headings ✅
2. Sort headings alphabetically ✅
3. Find each heading in the doc
4. Cut-paste section in the appropriate position of the doc (or append to a new doc in the correct order)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can it be assumed that there's only one heading per section and that it is either at the beginning of the doc or right after a page break?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, that's a fair assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You want to sort a series of document sections according to the section's heading text.

#### Solution:

Assuming that each section starts with a heading, you can do the following:

- Iterate through all the body elements and get info on which indexes does each section start and end (based on the location of the headings). Methods [getNumChildren](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getnumchildren) and [getChild](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildchildindex) would be useful here. You should end up with an array of section objects, each containing the start and end indexes as well as the heading text.
- [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the section objects according to the heading text.
- Iterate through the sections array, and append the children corresponding to each section indexes to the end of the document. Useful methods here are [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#copy) and the different append methods (e.g. [appendParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphparagraph)). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog)'s a related question.
- Please notice that only `PARAGRAPH`, `TABLE` and `LIST_ITEM` are appended on the sample below; if there are other element types present in your original content, you should add the corresponding condition to the code.
- When appending the elements, it's important to use the original elements [Attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute); otherwise, things like list bullets might not get appended (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833389/google-apps-script-fails-to-copy-bullets-from-one-document-to-other-document)).
- After the copied elements are appended, remove the original ones (here you can use [removeFromParent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element#removefromparent)).

#### Code sample:

```
function findHeading1s() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  const parType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
  const headingType = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
  const numChildren = body.getNumChildren();
  let sections = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    const child = body.getChild(i);
    let section;
    if (child.getType() === parType) {
      const par = child.asParagraph();
      const parText = par.getText();
      if (par.getHeading() === headingType && parText != "") {
        section = {
          startIndex: i,
          headingText: parText
        }
        if (sections.length) sections[sections.length - 1]["endIndex"] = i - 1;
        sections.push(section);
      }
    }
  }
  const lastSection = sections.find(section => !section["endIndex"]);
  if (lastSection) lastSection["endIndex"] = numChildren - 1;
  sections.sort((a,b) => a.headingText.localeCompare(b.headingText));
  sections.forEach(section => {
    const { startIndex, endIndex } = section;
    for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
      const element = body.getChild(i);
      const copy = element.copy();
      const type = element.getType();
      const attributes = element.getAttributes();
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
        body.appendParagraph(copy).setAttributes(attributes);  
      } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
        body.appendTable(copy).setAttributes(attributes);  
      } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        body.appendListItem(copy).setAttributes(attributes);  
      }
    }
  });
  for (let i = numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    body.getChild(i).removeFromParent();
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that italic/bold formatting of some paragraphs are not being copied over into the sorted output (neither are hyperlinks). Any tips on how might that be achieved? (I successfully added INLINE_IMAGE support, but don't see any similar approaches with italic/bold/hyperlink formatting). Thanks!