# Cannot set GlyphType to number Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to create an App Script where existing text (paragraphs and headings) will be turned into listed items where I can set a specific NestingLevel and use the  DIGIT_NESTED (or NUMBER) Glyph type. I can create the list from the text but the GlyphType is changed to letters instead of staying as a Number.
Also it seems the DIGIT_NESTED [listPreset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/list-preset?hl=en) doesn't appear to exist for [Glyph Types](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type) for Google Docs...

**Example text:**
Text here.
Paragraph under first text.
Another paragraph here.

**endgoal - it becomes:**
1. Text here.       *(has GlyphType: Number, NestingLevel: 0)*.
1.1 Paragraph under first text.       *(has GlyphType: Number, NestingLevel: 1).*
1.2 Another paragraph here.       *(has GlyphType: Number, NestingLevel: 2)*

**Current output which isn't what the endgoal is**
1. Text here.
a. Paragraph under first text.
i. Another paragraph here.

I've tried creating the functionality by changing the paragraph-element itself (see first code-block below) - which created the list-style however the numbering and list-item functionality is lost since it then becomes a paragraph-type (and I want it to still be of the type LIST_ITEM.

*changing the paragraph element code:*
`paragraph.setText(body.insertListItem(indexOfTextContent, textContent).setNestingLevel(calculatedNestingLevel).setIndentStart(40).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER));`

This is as far as I've come. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787504/apps-script-appendlistitem-with-correct-glyphtype) that appending can reset the glyph type and thus tried to reset it after inserting the ListItem into Body (as seen in the else-statement below), but it doesn't fix the glyph-issue.
I've checked what GlyphType and NestingLevel the ListItems have when I've edited the list manually in docs and it is GlyphType: Number, NestingLevel 0 then 1 then 2 (as written on end-goal example above).

```
// paragraph is a prop sent into the function and is the Paragraph we want to change
// calculatedNestingLevel is a prop sent into the function with sets 0, 1, 2 according to the paragraphs position in the document. 
// parentListItem is a prop set to the first ListItem to make sure they belong to the same list.

const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
const textContent = paragraph.getText();
const indexOfTextContent = body.getChildIndex(paragraph);

if (calculatedNestingLevel === 0) { 
 const listItem1 = body.insertListItem(indexOfTextContent, textContent).setNestingLevel(indexNr).setIndentStart(40).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER);
 parentListItem[0] = (listItem1);
} else { 
 const listItem = body.insertListItem(indexOfTextContent, textContent).setListId(parentListItem[0]).setNestingLevel(calculatedNestingLevel).setIndentStart(40).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER);
 listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER);
}
// delete the paragraph to eliminate duplicate text
 body.removeChild(paragraph);
```

Comment: *1.2 Another paragraph ... NestingLevel: 2)* I suspect **Level 2** is `1.2.1` not `1.2` which is **Level 1** like as `1.1`, `1.3` etc.

Comment: You might want to file a bug in [https://issuetracker.google.com/](https://issuetracker.google.com/). Upon replicating the issue, correct glyph type can only be achieved when using nesting level 0. As list contain a nesting level greater than 0, the glyph type set was not reflected correctly.